# UITableView ¿Cómo poner una imagen y texto de fondo cuando no hay datos

Tags: ios, objective-c

Necesito poner una imagen y un pequeño texto cuando se abra un UITableView vacio (sin datos).

Adjunto la imagen de un ejemplo que he visto por internet a ver cómo se podría hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias por vuestra ayuda @mhergon y @jherran.

Con vuestra ayuda la he combiando y ya me funciona.

Pongo el código que he realizado.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if ([self.sortedKeys count] == 0) {

        NoDataMedicionesUIView *sample = [[NoDataMedicionesUIView alloc] initWithFrame:medicionesTableView.frame];

        medicionesTableView.backgroundView= sample;

    } else {
        medicionesTableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    return [self.sortedKeys count];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mi la forma mas fácil es creando un XIB con un `UIView`. A partir de eso, colocarlo como header de la primera sección cuando tu `dataSource` venga vacío. La ventaja, es que si el XIB es lo suficientemente configurable lo puedes utilizar en multiples tablas, proyectos, etc.

Sería algo así:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.dataSource count]) {
        ...
    } else {
        NoData *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:noDataViewID];
        return headerView;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.dataSource count]) {
        ...
    } else {
        return tableView.frame.size.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: El viewForHeaderInSection solo se activa si hay items no?

Comment: @Shadros no, se muestra independientemente de que haya datos o no.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes dos opciones, o utilizas la propiedad `backgroundView` del `UITableView` para color ahí la imagen y el texto que necesites, o bien, detrás del `UITableView`, colocas la imagen y el texto y ocultas uno y muestras el otro en función de lo que necesites.
Recuerda que en el primer caso, hay que crear un `UIView` para asignar a `backgroundView` y después meter lo que quieres dentro de ese `UIView`